# Simple SQL query to flatten multiple attributes in a row

Tags: sql, postgresql, case, pgadmin, flatten

I first tried solving my problem in Excel with no easy fix, so decided to give it a shot in SQL (on PostgreSQL/pgAdminIII), where I am a beginner, and where I didn't find a satisfying solution.

My goal is to "flatten" a data set containing similar attributes in a single row, which should have a row of their own.

An example might clarify. My data lists shopping bags and their contents as follows:

```
id material color fruit1 fruit2 fruit3 
1  cotton   red   apple  banana cherry
2  paper    blue  apple  cherry
3  plastic  red   banana
```

I need to create a table with a new line for each fruit, so the result of the query should be something like:

```
id material color fruit  
1  cotton   red   apple  
1  cotton   red   banana 
1  cotton   red   cherry
2  paper    blue  apple
2  paper    blue  cherry
3  plastic  red   banana
```

So far, I came up with a query involving **CASE**, but this only returns the first match, and so doesn't return all the needed lines.

```
SELECT  
  id,
    (CASE 
        WHEN 'apple' IN(fruit1, fruit2, fruit3) THEN 'apple_exh'        
        WHEN 'banana' IN(fruit1, fruit2, fruit3) THEN 'banana_exh'
        WHEN 'cherry' IN(fruit1, fruit2, fruit3) THEN 'cherry_exh'              
        ELSE 'Error'
    END) as "Fruit_Here"
FROM 
  mydb.shopping
WHERE 
 'apple' IN(fruit1, fruit2, fruit3)
 OR
 'banana' IN(fruit1, fruit2, fruit3)
 OR
 'cherry' IN(fruit1, fruit2, fruit3)

ORDER BY id;
```

Returns

```
id; fruit_here
1;"apple_exh"
2;"apple_exh"
3;"banana_exh"
```

It would be really nice if a trick existed to allow CASE to return **all matches**, and not just the first. My current workaround using a sequence of **CASE** and **UNION ALL** (see below example for apples and bananas) works, but is unrealistically tedious, as my full data includes around 30 fruits (and possibly I should apply the same "flattening" to vegetables, also initially on a single row).

```
SELECT  
  id,
    (CASE 
        WHEN 'apple' IN(fruit1, fruit2, fruit3) THEN 'apple_exh'                        
        ELSE 'Error'
    END) as "Fruit_Here"
FROM 
  mydb.shopping
WHERE 
 'apple' IN(fruit1, fruit2, fruit3)

UNION ALL

SELECT  
  id,
    (CASE 
        WHEN 'banana' IN(fruit1, fruit2, fruit3) THEN 'banana_exh'
        ELSE 'Error'
    END) as "Fruit_Here"
FROM 
  mydb.shopping
WHERE 
 'banana' IN(fruit1, fruit2, fruit3)

 UNION ALL

 SELECT  
  id,
    (CASE 
        WHEN 'cherry' IN(fruit1, fruit2, fruit3) THEN 'cherry_exh'
        ELSE 'Error'
    END) as "Fruit_Here"
FROM 
  mydb.shopping
WHERE 
 'cherry' IN(fruit1, fruit2, fruit3)

ORDER BY id, "Fruit_Here";
```

Returns

```
id; fruit_here
1;"apple_exh"
1;"banana_exh"
1;"cherry_exh"
2;"apple_exh"
2;"cherry_exh"
3;"banana_exh"
```

**My question:** Is there any other obvious way to perform this task in SQL, without having to duplicate code for each type of fruit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need a select statement for each column:

```
select id, material, color, fruit1 from mydb.shopping where fruit1 is not null
union 
select id, material, color, fruit2 from mydb.shopping where fruit2 is not null
union 
select id, material, color, fruit3 from mydb.shopping where fruit3 is not null
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for reading through my question and posting this! This was indeed the simple solution I was looking for. It was of great help knowing the separate select statements actually line up in the same column the results by position in the statement, regardless of the source column name. All fruits therefore ended up aligned in a column labeled "fruit1", which was precisely what I needed.

Answer (score -1):

I have done this using sql for reporting, but I can not find my code.
But here is what I have found doing a quick search.
[Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)